# PyCharm module reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-module

Recently I met a problem in a new python project. There are many reference errors which PyCharm inspects for me which can run successfully.

The following is my file structure:
[image]

For example, in server/shuma/game/session.py, the former developer imported some python file in server/shuma/game with code as following:

[image]

And PyCharm finds some reference errors (but the project can run, it means it can find the file in server/shuma/game), thus I can't use 'ctrl+B' to go to some variable:

[image]

I tried to add '..' before game, everything came back to normal and I could use 'ctrl+B'  to find the declaration :

[image]
[image]

My question being: obviously python can find 'game' without '..' before it, but PyCharm can't do that job and regards that as an error ,the project is so large that it's impossible to add '..' or '.' before the path.

Can I change some settings in PyCharm to use 'ctrl+B' without changing the code?

Comment: **Settings -> Project -> Project Structure**, you can set _source directories_. Those directories will be available in PYTHONPATH both for execution and code analysis.

Comment: thank you ! I change server/shuma(the package upon game) to be source root and the problem disappear !